# What is better to use with Selenium rspec or Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, testing, webdriver

I have a web application to test and I am new to using Ruby. Would be great if someone can share their experiences if rspec is better or Test::Unit with Selenium ?

(Just an FYI the website under test is not made using Ruby on Rails.)

Comment: Rspec is better, period.

Answer (score 1):

It's debatable and a matter of preference.  I'd suggest using [rspec](http://rspec.info/).  It reads more like a human-readable language than Test::Unit, and it has strong community support.  You should be able to google around for lots of examples that fit your specific testing needs, and I'd also suggest the [Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book), which will tell you all you need to know and then some.